# xamarin forms - Binding text to a label in xaml - can I cut out the end of the text?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

Evening All,

Have a label...

```
  <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Text="{Binding Email}"/>
```

So yeah, this works fine...However it displays the full email...

JohnnyRambo@JR.com,
MovesLikeJagger@MJ.com,
HugsForFree@HF.com

Q being can I remove the domain name from the xaml page? to output...

JohnnyRambo,
MovesLikeJagger,
HugsForFree

Thanks for any replies

Comment: add a read only `EmailDisplay` property to your model, or use an IValueConverter in the XAML to do it

Comment: OK cool. Ta Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason's opinion, you can use [Xamarin.Forms Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to remove the domain name. I do one sample that you can take a look:

Firstly, create one model class that display Eamil or other info.

```
public class persominfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public partial class Page34 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<persominfo> persons { get; set; }
    public Page34()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        persons = new ObservableCollection<persominfo>()
        {
            new persominfo(){Name="JR",Email="JohnnyRambo@JR.com"},
            new persominfo(){Name="MJ",Email="MovesLikeJagger@MJ.com"},
            new persominfo(){Name="HF",Email="HugsForFree@HF.com"}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Then I use ListView to display these info, using data binding to convert any Eamil property into a string that you want.

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="FormsSample.simplecontrol.Page34"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:FormsSample.converter">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converter:EmailConverter x:Key="converter1" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding persons}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Text="{Binding Email, Converter={StaticResource converter1}}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding Email}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This is EmailConverter ,Value converter classes can have properties and generic parameters

```
 public class EmailConverter : IValueConverter
{      
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string  emaildisplay = (string)value;
        string[] words = emaildisplay.Split('@');
        if(words[0]!=null)
        {
            return words[0];
        }
        return null;
       
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ahh ok cool. Thanks for the reply Cherry Bu

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Jason's comment:

```
public string PartialEmail {
    get {
        s = ... write code here to get substring you want ...
        return s;
    }
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
Text="{Binding PartialEmail}"
```

In other words, it is up to you to code a property that has the value you want to display.

In general, its best to have UI (XAML) only concerned with UI; any calculations or manipulation of values should be in code (cs).